# 500 error trying to authenticate via AWS Application load balancer and Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cognito, amazon-elb, aws-alb

I am trying to setup Authentication for some certain routes using AWS internet-facing Application load balancer.

I've done all the steps from the official AWS documentation, and also using this one:
https://www.thorntech.com/2018/09/user-authentication-alb-cognito/

I was testing via load balancer's DNS name, and it redirects me properly to the login form of Cognito, but after I am logged in it redirects to the load balancer, and it gives *500 Internal Server Error*. URL is like so https://xxxxx.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/oauth2/idpresponse?code=.......

Do you know, which can be the causes of it, and what should I configure else to make it working?

`openid` is allowed

Comment: We have exactly the same issue, opened a ticket with AWS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question - the problem is with the security groups. 
You have to have a security group with the open port 443 on your load balancer!

Comment: Can you elaborate please? To/from, etc. The default rules on an ALB sitting in public subnets is to allow inbound 80/443 from 0.0.0.0. No outbound restrictions. What rules did you add aside from these?

Comment: Yes, so ALB needs to be in the public subnet, but the _inbound_ rules are set in te security group, and should allow 80/443. Not sure about the 0.0.0.0, but it should do. Does the traffic go through 443 for you?

Comment: Fir posterity: our ALB was configured with incorrect "email" scope. Changing scope to "openid" on the ALB HTTPS listener rule, fixed our issue.