# AWS Cognito and application load balancer: Error in SAML response processing RedirectUri is not registered with the client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to use the AWS Application load balancer to authenticate using Cognito to my Idp using SAML.

I'm having an issue somewhat similar to this one [500 error trying to authenticate via AWS Application load balancer and Cognito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53612469/500-error-trying-to-authenticate-via-aws-application-load-balancer-and-cognito)

But I get a specific error saying:

**Error in SAML response processing RedirectUri is not registered with the client**

I get this error as part of the idpresponse posted to my load balancer.

When I look at the users in Cognito, I can see my user is being created correctly. But I am not getting redirected to my application behind the load balancer.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 7):

Ah I figured it out. It was due to the callback url in cognito was in uppercase. I need to specify the callback url in lowercase and it worked.

Comment: I had this exact issue, as the CDK/CloudFormation generated ALB domain name had uppercase characters in it. Browsers will auto lowercase domain names!

Comment: For me somehow the trailing / in the redirect URL was missing

Comment: For me also trailing / fixed it